# Java Swing GUI Hidden Input

Tags: java, input

I made a simple JFrame with Swing. I want to know how I would go about making a non-visible input that would open up another JFrame I have in another class. (Like cheat codes in video games, you enter a combination and something happens.) I am not sure how to capture the user input without a text field.

Comment: use a keylistener to listen for pressed keys. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [keybinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) attached to your JFrame. You would want to store keystrokes as a String internally and after each keystroke, see whether the user has entered a recognizable cheat code or just listen for a return keypress as a delimiter for the code.

Keep in mind that if a component within that JFrame has focus and also implements the same key bindings, then that component will take precedence over the JFrame, effectively intercepting the keystrokes.

Comment: keybining is the better solution (rather than keyListener) - this makes your code easier to understand and easier to maintain....